# Share Directive Scope with Transcluded Elements

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a reusable modal directive, but the transcluded elements create their own scope. Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/3KXAS/) of the issue. Here is how it works.

```
<button ng-click="show=!show">Show Modal</button>
<modal visible="show">
    <button ng-click="show=!show">X</button>
</modal>
```

Notice that the button to show it works, but the X does not close it, because the inner button is transcluded and creates its own scope. Is there any way to link the transcluded scope to the current scope of the directive? Or just stop it from creating its own scope? Here is the directive.

```
.directive('modal', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  template: "<div ng-style='bgstyling()' ng-transclude></div>",
  transclude: true,
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(val) {
      elem[0].style.visibility = val ? 'visible' : 'hidden';   
    });
    scope.bgstyling = function() {
      return {
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0',
        'left': '0',
        'bottom': '0',
        'right': '0',
        'backgroundColor': attrs.bgColor || '#000',
        'opacity': attrs.opacity || '0.85'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

})

*** UPDATE ***

I think the answer might have something to do with the transclude function parameter of the link function. This is what I just tried, but still isn't quite working.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, nullC, transclude) {
    transclude(scope, function(clone) {
      elem.append($compile(clone)(scope));
    });
    ...
```

Comment: I think the `X` is getting scope from isolated directive scope. But setting `show` in the html has no affect as directive scope property name is `ngModalShow`

Comment: @Chandermani, yeah that was just the quick example I put up. See it now. I want the visibility to change when scope.show changes. I think the key might be the transcludeFn of the link, but I don't see much on how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the controller responsible for updating the scope helps - the scope is shared after all and you probably want the logic for updating it in the same place.

```js
.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
})
```

And the template:

```html
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <button ng-click="toggle()">Show Modal</button>
  <modal visible="show">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">X</button>
  </modal>
</div>
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcallister/3KXAS/6/)

Comment: To be more specific you can also reference the controller in the directive itself.

Comment: This works well. Why does it work to use toggle(), but show=!show fails? They literally do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The close button is specific to the Modal directive so you could just put the button in the directive html and avoid the scoping issue.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46tMh/2/)

```
...      
template: "<div ng-style='bgstyling()'><button ng-click=\"show=!show\">X</button></div>",
...
```

You can also access the parent scope if necessary but I prefer to try and keep scopes as simple as possible.

**Edit**
You can still use transclude like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46tMh/6/)

```
...
template: "
    <div ng-style='bgstyling()'>
        <button ng-click=\"show=!show\">X</button>
        <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
    ",
transclude: true,
...
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do. I want to create a modal that will display any of the inner content. The way you describe is not reusable. Thanks tho.

Comment: You can still use transclude as before. The content will appear within the inner div rather than the outer div as shown in the edit above.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is that I don't want the button in the directive, it needs to be able to close it while being transcluded.

Comment: Ok cool that sounds fair. I prefer not to use transclude if I can help it and usually pass the data via scope in order to be more explicit.